# grails help command is acting strange

Tags: java, grails, ubuntu

Why is this happening when I use the grails help feature?

```
nobody@nobody-desktop:~$ grails help create-app
Welcome to Grails 1.3.2 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/nobody/Downloads/grails-1.3.2

Base Directory: /home/nobody
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 2454ms.
Running script /home/nobody/Downloads/grails-1.3.2/scripts/Help_.groovy
Environment set to development

    grails create-app -- Creates a Grails application for the given name

Usage (optionals marked with *):
    grails [environment]* create-app

nobody@nobody-desktop:~$
```

is some configuration messed up on my computer? **it shouldn't take 2.5 seconds to get the help output now should it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the boilerplate grails startup output:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.2 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/nobody/Downloads/grails-1.3.2

Base Directory: /home/nobody
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 2454ms.
```

This is the output from Grails indicating that it has found a script that matches the command you executed (i.e. help->Help_.groovy)

```
Running script /home/nobody/Downloads/grails-1.3.2/scripts/Help_.groovy
Environment set to development
```

This is the actual output of the Help for create-app:

```
    grails create-app -- Creates a Grails application for the given name

Usage (optionals marked with *):
    grails [environment]* create-app
```

Comment: but it does this every time, and it takes 2.5 seconds to get the help output, I think something is wrong?

Comment: Others have complained about this as well.  As you can see from the output, the delay is all happening because of dependency resolution. There were some discussions on the Grails mailing list a while back to disable dependency resolution via a configuration, but as far as I know, this feature is still not available.